# A dash (-) in a char data type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I'm trying to insert data into a table in my database that has a PK column that has a data type of `char`.  There are currently records in that column that are formatted like this `27-5`.  However, I cannot seem to think of a way to replicate this with an insert statement.

My current insert statement obviously just performs the concatenation manually:

`Insert into kc.ep_act_steps Values (1,1-3,'Some Example Text',NULL,3,1)`

That column happens to be the creation of the last two columns in reverse order.  How can I achieve this?

Edit: Updated with table definition (removed some unneccessary key stuff)

```
USE [ICKC_2]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [kc].[ep_act_steps]    Script Date: 06/18/2013 17:27:35 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON


SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON


SET ANSI_PADDING ON


CREATE TABLE [kc].[ep_act_steps](
[act_type] [char](16) NOT NULL,
[act_id] [char](16) NOT NULL,
[description] [varchar](2000) NULL,
[ep_procedure] [int] NULL,
[display_order] [smallint] NULL,
[org_id] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK__ep_act_steps__22751F6C] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[act_type] ASC,
[act_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Edit: Cannot enclose in apostrophes despite having all PK constraints turned off using `sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'`.  Using apostrophes results in the following error: `Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ep_act_steps__22751F6C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'kc.ep_act_steps'.'

Comment: What is the table definition? Why isn't this a computed column?

Comment: I'll update my post with the table definition I got by right-clicking and hitting create to

Comment: It's a string. You need to enclose in quotes. -1 for not putting what, if any, error you are getting.

Comment: Huh?  Why doesn't `INSERT into yourTable(pkCol) SELECT '27-5';` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Insert into kc.ep_act_steps Values ('1','1-3','Some Example Text',NULL,3,1)
```

Comment: It will not allow me to enter it with apostrophes in such a way, I get the following error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__ep_act_steps__22751F6C'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'kc.ep_act_steps'.  However I have disabled all constraints

Comment: @Jfabs Your primary key **is** a constraint as you can see from the table definition.

Comment: I realize that, however I have disabled all constraints using `sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'`

Comment: You already have a record with 1-3 in the primary key column.

Comment: You can't disable the primary key constraint.  The primary key must be unique.  Why would you want to insert a duplicate?

Comment: This first insert was simply for the purposes of testing the insert statement as I had developed it outside of SQL server

Comment: No. You can't disable the primary key constraint -- EVER.

Comment: Think of the Primary Key as both a unique constraint and a unique index.  Technically you can disable the primary key but then you can't access the table at all :)